# Use .htacess to specify default filename is the current directory's name?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is there a way to make apache (eg: through the .htacess file) base the default filename for a directory url on the directory name itself? I could do this one directory at a time by modifying the httpd.conf for that directory, but it would be handy to be able to do this in a more global/recursive sort of way.

Examples to hopefully clarify:

`http://example.com/dir1/` => would load `http://example.com/dir1/dir1.php`

`http://example.com/some/long/path/` => would load `http://example.com/some/long/path/path.php`

`http://example.com/jumboHotdogs/` => would load `http://example.com/jumboHotdogs/jumboHotdogs.php`

Perhaps using DirectoryIndex? Or Mod Rewrite? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mod_rewrite can definitely do that, try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}%1.php [L]
```